# How can I import Socket.IO-Client-Swift to a Swift 5 project?

Tags: swift, xcode, socket.io, swift5

When I add [Socket.IO-Client-Swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) to my project, I get this error:

> SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'Starscream')

Answer (score 2):

Version 16 of Socket.IO-Client-Swift [adds Swift 5 compatibility](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/releases/tag/v16.0.1). If you're using CocoaPods, include this in your Podfile and run `pod update Socket.IO-Client-Swift`:

```
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your error. You need to update your Xcode.
Then you can use `pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 15.0.0'`
For now and that error your supported version is 14 of Socket.IO-Client-Swif and you can use `pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 14.0.0'`

Comment: error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'Starscream') - I am not able to create and run iOS new apps. That's total no-go for NativeScript to me.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not use NativeScript so I do not know how it works. Here was answer for swift, socket.io and xcode.